# Can I use ardent in laravel to validate fields that I don't want it to save?

Tags: php, laravel, ardent

I want Ardent to check that password and password confirmation match...yet, I obviously don't want to store password confirmation in the database.  So how do I get Ardent to do it's stuff and validate but not try to save the password confirmation?

Note:  the validation is failing anyway as it is not seeing the password_confirmation property value.  I imagine it's looking for it under the model attributes, whereas I have just set it as a private property.  If I set it as the model's attribute though, it will try to save this to the database.

```
public static $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'first_name' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3',
        'surname' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required'
);

//user object gets populated
$this->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give your class a property of

```
public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;
```

And that automatically purges any properties not used in the database, see [here](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#automatically-purge-redundant-form-data).